# URL regular expression pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I would like to parse URLs with Regular Expressions and find a pattern that matches with `https://*.global`.

**[Here is my URL test string on regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/QKq2pJ/1)**

Ideally, the regex would return `https://app8.global` instead of cover other `https` string.

```js
const URL = `https://temp/"https://app8.global"https://utility.localhost/`;
const regex = /https:\/\/(.+?)\.global(\/|'|"|`)/gm;
const found = URL.match(regex);
console.log(found);
```

How would I manipulate the regex so it will return the `https://*.global`?

Comment: Do you mean to extract `(.+?)` part?

Comment: Right, I want to extract `app1 ~ app8`

Comment: Just use `/\bhttps?:\/\/([^\/]+?)\.global\b/i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to exclude slashes from the starting part, otherwise it'll match things from the previous url:

```js
const regex = /https:\/\/([^\/]+?)\.global(\/|'|"|`)/gm;
```

Now, you can convert the weird 4 character or with a character group:

```js
const regex = /https:\/\/([^\/]+?)\.global[\/'"`]/gm;
```

And now you can get the matches and trim off that last character:

```js
const matches = URL.match(regex).map(v => v.slice(0, -1));
```

Then, `matches` would evaluate to `["https://app8.global"]`.

Comment: What's the difference between the two regex-es?

Comment: The two regexes I gave are functionally equivalent, however the second is more readable in my opinion.

Comment: @Aplet123 Thanks for your answer. I added lookahead (`?=`) to filter tail `"` and `'`. The regular expression would be `https:\/\/([^\/]+?)\.global(?=[\/'"`])`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Group RegExp.$1

```js
const URL = `https://temp/"https://app8.global"https://utility.localhost/`;
const regex = /(https:\/\/([^\/]+?)\.global[\/'"`])/;
const found = URL.match(regex);
console.log(RegExp.$1);
```

Comment: if we put 3 slashes in url .which is wrong eg:https:///t6app1.global/ right string is 2 slashes exept 3rd slash consider whole string  https://t6app1.global/ check regex in 101regex website to better understand.

Comment: I understand the literal use but I'm wondering how `https://temp/"` part is excluded.

Comment: reason is next part of u asked in regex u can see .global is matter , u want to consider whole string but  this part does not  match https://temp/" with .global string so why is excluded